# About reference in appendix

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, appendices, subdividing

After adding an additional reference section in the appendix part, I want to the number of each reference item is after the number of reference in the main body of the paper.

So that it should be like this:

> Main Part
>
> Reference
>
> [1]
>
> [2]
>
> Appendix
>
> Reference
>
> [3]
>
> [4]

Not the following:

> Main Part
>
> Reference
>
> [1]
>
> [2]
>
> Appendix
>
> Reference
>
> [1]
>
> [2]

How to do the job?

Part of my latex file is:

```
\documentclass{vldb}  
\begin{document}  

............

\begin{thebibliography}  
\bibitem{anh2005inverted}  
V.~N. Anh and A.~Moffat.  
\newblock {Inverted index compression using word-aligned binary codes}.  
\newblock {\em Information Retrieval}, 8(1):151--166, 2005.  

\bibitem{baeza-fast}  
R.~Baeza-Yates.  
\newblock {A fast set intersection algorithm for sorted sequences}.  
\newblock In {\em Combinatorial Pattern Matching}, pages 400--408, 2004.  
\end{thebibliography}  

\begin{appendix}   
\begin{thebibliography}  
\bibitem{buttcher2006trec}  
S.~B{\"u}ttcher, C.~L.~A. Clarke, and I.~Soboroff.  
\newblock {The TREC 2006 terabyte track}.  
\newblock In {\em Proc.\ 15th Text Retrieval Conference (TREC)}, 2006.  

\bibitem{fisher1963statistical}  
R.~Fisher and F.~Yates.  
\newblock {\em {Statistical tables for biological, agricultural and medical  
research}}.  
\newblock Oliver and Boyd, 1963.  
\end{thebibliography}  
\end{appendix}  
\end{document}
```

Comment: The two examples are identical. Also, a minimal working example would be helpful.

Comment: @lockstep I am so careless.

Comment: As I said before, more information is needed. As a minimum, what packages (if any) do you use to create your "reference sections"? What's your document class? A complete example would make it easier to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are creating your bibliographies "manually" (i.e. without the help of BibTeX or biber), you have to adjust the value of the counter `enumiv` (which is used by the `thebibliography` environment) at the start of the second bibliography.

Note: The corrext syntax is `\begin{bibliography}{9}` (with `9` representing the width of your widest biblabel). And `\appendix` is a command, not an environment. (I'm assuming that the `vldb` documentclass, which is not part of my TeX distribution, does things the same way as the standard classes.)

```
\documentclass{article}  

\begin{document}  

............

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{anh2005inverted}  
V.~N. Anh and A.~Moffat.  
\newblock {Inverted index compression using word-aligned binary codes}.  
\newblock {\em Information Retrieval}, 8(1):151--166, 2005.  

\bibitem{baeza-fast}  
R.~Baeza-Yates.  
\newblock {A fast set intersection algorithm for sorted sequences}.  
\newblock In {\em Combinatorial Pattern Matching}, pages 400--408, 2004.  
\end{thebibliography}  

\appendix

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\setcounter{enumiv}{2}

\bibitem{buttcher2006trec}  
S.~B{\"u}ttcher, C.~L.~A. Clarke, and I.~Soboroff.  
\newblock {The TREC 2006 terabyte track}.  
\newblock In {\em Proc.\ 15th Text Retrieval Conference (TREC)}, 2006.  

\bibitem{fisher1963statistical}  
R.~Fisher and F.~Yates.  
\newblock {\em {Statistical tables for biological, agricultural and medical  
research}}.  
\newblock Oliver and Boyd, 1963.  
\end{thebibliography}  

\end{document}
```